# Powershell list recursively files attributes to csv

Tags: powershell, getfileversion

I am trying to fill a csv file with all the attributes of the files contained within a folder. I have troubles recovering the fileversion & assembly

```
$arr = @()
gci C:\Temp -recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Size (Get-Item $_.Length/1MB)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastAccess $_.LastAccessTime 
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Creation $_.CreationTime
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastWrite $_.LastWriteTime
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty ReadOnly $_.IsReadOnly
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty FullName $_.FullName
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Date (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Version ($_.FileVersion)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Assembly ($_.AssemblyVersion)
$arr += $obj
}
$arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "c:\temp\File\report.csv"
```

Comment: so whats the error?

Comment: None, field is empty even if there is a dll in the folder with a version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)The issue what you are facing is because of permission. Try running the script in elevated mode(run as administrator).
2)You should not try to save anything under C:\temp folder. Better to create a folder in D:\ or E:\ and put it over there as D:\temp_dump\report.csv
3)if you are putting get-item on the size, then that is not a valid one since you have to pick whatever inside the folder.

Below Script is working fine.

```
##########################################################

$arr = @()
$Folder_path="E:\PS"

gci $Folder_path | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | % {

$obj = New-Object PSObject

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Size (Get-ChildItem $Folder_path | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastAccess $_.LastAccessTime 

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Creation $_.CreationTime

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastWrite $_.LastWriteTime

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty ReadOnly $_.IsReadOnly

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty FullName $_.FullName

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Date (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Version ($_.FileVersion)

$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Assembly ($_.AssemblyVersion)

$arr += $obj

}

$arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "E:\report.csv"
```

#

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$arr = @()
gci C:\Temp -recurse -File -Filter *.dll |  % {
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Size (Get-Item $_.Length/1MB)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastAccess $_.LastAccessTime 
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Creation $_.CreationTime
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastWrite $_.LastWriteTime
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty ReadOnly $_.IsReadOnly
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty FullName $_.FullName
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Date (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Version ($_.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Assembly ([Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version)
$arr += $obj
}
$arr | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "c:\temp\File\report.csv"
```

you can simplify your code like this

```
gci C:\Temp -recurse -File -Filter *.dll |  % {
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Directory= $_.DirectoryName
Name= $_.Name
Size= $_.Length/1MB
Owner= ((Get-ACL $_.FullName).Owner)
LastAccess= $_.LastAccessTime 
Extension= $_.Extension
Creation= $_.CreationTime
LastWrite= $_.LastWriteTime
ReadOnly= $_.IsReadOnly
FullName= $_.FullName
Date= (Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm")
Version= ($_.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
Assembly= ([Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version)
}
} | Export-CSV -notypeinformation "c:\temp\File\report.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get fileversion you have to use this:

```
$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Version ($_.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
```

You cannot get AssemblyVersion from VersionInfo